# Spring boot tests - out of memory issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, out-of-memory

I am trying to run tests using maven. Application contains junit tests & integration tests. Following configuration is used:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <argLine>
                        -Xverify:none
                        -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
                        -Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -ea
                        -XX:MaxRAM=1000m
                        -Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}
                        -Dspring.test.context.cache.maxSize=1
                    </argLine>
                    <excludedGroups>${env.MVN_EXCLUDED_TESTS}</excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Tests uses common configuration in nearly all cases with one test profile (nothing is suspicious to me).

I have tried to lower number of cached contexts to 1 by setting maxSize property. That works, but without effect on OOM issue. So I have captured heapdump, but I have no idea whats going on there. I can see 35 instances of `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory` and 34 instances of `org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl` which takes lots of memory (see picture).

[image: memory allocation, suspect 1 = DefaultListableBeanFactory]

I have only find something about DefaultListableBeanFactory [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25619) but I doubt that thats the problem.

Do you have any ideas what to check or modify to lower memory usage? Or is there realy any memory leak? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to lower the memory usage, why don't you just give it more memory? It'll give it back after it's finished, you don't need to limit it to 1GB.

Comment: I need to run tests on enviroment where I have restricted resources

Comment: Which Spring (Boot) version are you using... Finally if you are using Spring Security you might be running into this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26266

Comment: Spring boot 2.5.3, Spring 5.3.9

Comment: M. Denium thanks, problem is solved when I paradoxically change `spring.test.context.cache.maxSize` to something bigger like 24. When is set too low, then there is really memory leak and some proxy classes are not GC. Also I have noticed some cache from Sleuth were holding reference to some other classes that was impossible to GC (cca 80 MB decrease). When I have fixed both I have no OOM anymore.